# Getting the scene an object is in (blender 2.9)

Tags: python, objects, scene

It's fairly easy to get the objects that are in a scene:

```
dict(myScene.collection.all_objects) # mapping from name to object.
```

But how to go the other way?

```
scene = magic_get_linked_scenes(myOb)
```

One could iterate through all scenes:

```
linked_scenes = []
for scene_name, scene in dict(bpy.data.scenes):
  for ob_name, ob in dict(scene.collection.all_objects):
     if ob.name == name:
         linked_scenes.append(scene) # checking object equality should also work.
```

But this is clumsy and slow if there are a very large number of objects. Is there a better way?

Comment: Best practice is to get all objects of the scene in *context*: `list(bpy.context.scene.objects)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object.users_scene` seems to show the scenes using the object.

Blender's Python Console is very useful when finding this stuff out. If you start typing and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> Auto Complete shows you all the options you have:

[image]